# How to check missing open or closing double quotes (") using bash script?

Tags: bash

I have CSV file. That file contains 21 fields. one field had double quotes opened but the closing double quote is missing in one of the record in file
eg:

```
422556565,22562546-2562625,postalcode,"waiting list
```

In the above example closing double code has missed in last field. I want to check whether any opening or closing double codes are missing in that file. if it is missing, need record number. For example if closing or opening double codes are missing in 70th record, i need the exact record number

only want to know whether there are lines where the number of double quotes is odd

Comment: What if part of what's being quoted is the newline? A value in CSV can span multiple lines.

Comment: yes that file has above 2000 lines (Records)

Answer (score -1):

For *[...] only want to know whether there are lines where the number of double quotes is odd*

You can use this:

```
/^$/ { print "Empty line";next; }
{ print $0 "   NF=" gsub(/"/, "") }
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Oups, typo, I removed the extra characters.